# (Keras) split dataflow depending on inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am wondering if tensorflow/keras allows to do tricks as follows:

Let's say we have dataset with some features, where one feature has distribution from 0 to 200 and later from 250 to 400 (pic below).

[image]

Is this possible to build neural network consists of two models, where first layer will decide whether input should go into flow A (let's say < 230) or flow B (>= 230)?

This model should take as input one dataset and return one output, but in the middle decide where to push data further (flow A or flow B)?

PS.
I know that it can be done adding some logic in front of model with simple if statement and later build two separated models, but this is not the case :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can build a neural network model with an exclusive branching mechanism (if statement) but you can build a model that computes both outputs and also has a separate output to determine output validity (Validity would output a single number in range 0-1 indicating if output A or output B is valid), see image below for illustration.

[image: model]

On another note, this is probably not the best (or the most efficient) solution. I don't want to make assumptions about your data but I would for sure ask myself if I really need one end-to-end neural network. Looking at your dataset example I would for sure try random forest or other traditional ensemble method.